# Disabling angular function according depending on media query size

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I was wondering if there was a way for function to do nothing at a certain media size

I'm working on an ionic app which uses angular 1. Another way to somehow do it may be to identify the platform that the app is running and have an if statement that if ionic app is running on certain platform then perform necessary function

Comment: What does *disable a function* mean?

Comment: your question is not clear wat is it exactly that u r looking for..

Comment: I want a function to do nothing at a certain media size

Comment: `if( $(window).width() < 425px ) { // What ever you want }` ?

Comment: cool thanks it worked